# Find correlation in observed data

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I have a method that calculates a certain variable. This variable is biased by an error which should be related to the observables that were used to calculated the variable. I don't have an exact formula of the calculation and also no errors of the observables, therefore I can't just do error propagation.

I do have training data (the true error). Now I want to use machine learning to find the correlations between the input observables and the error of the calculated output. For now I tried to gather as many observables and used their statistics (mean, variance etc.) as "feature vectors" for machine learning. So far I tried approaches like SVR, linear Regression, SGD Regression etc. but all showed the same bad result.

I'm quite new in this field. So some things are still a little bit unclear to me. Do you have any ideas how to find the relations? Or do you think there is no relation at all? What if there are observables that are totally random; do they destroy the learning?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using machine learning to calculate the variable directly from the observables ?

Comment: I haven't but it is also not possible as I don't have the possibility to change the calculation.

Comment: So is it the case you have , observables, true output and error available? You could play around and see if you can get a better result with smaller errors  than the existing  "calculation". Failing that you can use machine learning to build a mapping directly between observables and error. Without any idea of the form of the data and errors it's a challenge to be more precise.

Comment: I have the observables. Then the output is calculated in a "black box". The output is not exact. It has an error. I have training data which has true error data. Now I want to find the relation between the input observables and the error of the output. It's really not about the "output", it's about the error.

Comment: Just to be clear, if you could make another black box, without error, that wouldn't be of use ?